# PHP активный пункт меню

Tags: php, html, css

Есть следующий код:

```
<?php $url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];?>
<div class="menu_nav">
    <ul>
        <li <?php if ($url == "/" or $url == "/index.html") {echo 'class="active"';}?>><a href="/">Сервис</a></li>
        <li <?php if ($url == "/guaranty.html") {echo 'class="active"';}?>><a href="/guaranty.html">Гарантии</a></li>
        <li <?php if ($url == "/price.html") {echo 'class="active"';}?>><a href="/price.html">Цены</a></li>
        <li <?php if ($url == "/sovet.html" or $url == "/errors/") {echo 'class="active"';}?>><a href="/sovet.html">Советы</a></li>
        <!-- <li <?php if ($url == "contact") {echo 'class="active"';}?>><a href="/contacts">Контакты</a></li> -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

Нужно подсветить пункт "Советы" на любой странице каталога /errors/. Пробовал добавлять в условие `$url == "/errors/*.html"` - не помогло.

Comment: Проверить строку $ на вхождение подстроки  "errors" , если есть значит подсвечивать. К примеру stripos  if ($url==  "/sovet.html" || stripos($url,"errors")) ...

Comment: Я php не знаю , но это насколько мне известно язык с динамической типизацией поэтому когда функция найдёт индекс вхождения,  то int трансформируется в булевое  значение , если я ошибаюсь значит  stripos(...) != false добавите

Comment: '$url == "/errors/*.html" - не помогло.' - это не помогло потому что у вас просто происходит проверка на идентичность между строками, в данном случае '*' такой же символ как и остальные в строке. Строка в переменной url посимвольно сравнивается с той которую вы указали явно как литерал

Comment: @ДимаЕрохин Про проверку на идентичность догадался и экспериментировал с этой звездочкой во всех плоскостях).
stripos($url,"errors") помогло, спасибо большое!